# Дно и днище — в чем разница?

Tags: употребление-слов

В чем разница? Сразу на ум приходит, что "днище" - это о чем-то большом, например, "днище корабля", но ведь можно сказать "дно корабля" и при этом "морское дно".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отчасти Вы правы. Но *"днище"*, согласно толковым словарям, мы употребляем, когда говорим о дне бочки или плоскодонного судна: *бочка упала с телеги, и* днище *вылетело*. А "дно" имеет более  широкое употребление: низ, основание какой-л. ёмкости, а также судна (дно стакана, но и дно судна); нижняя часть какого-л. углубления на земной поверхности (дно ямы); почва, грунт под водой моря, реки, озера и т.п. (морское дно).

Comment: Днище имеет еще одно значение! Днище - бесконечно длинный и наполненный событиями день. Бывают такие, просто жуть...

Comment: Можно ссылку на конкретный словарь, где бы утверждалось, что у бочки именно днище? Такое возможно только в силу несвободности образования множественного числа (донья), поэтому частенько можно услышать "днища" как множественное к дно, в т.ч. и по отношению к бочкам. Но о нормативности тут речи не идёт.

Comment: 1)http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E4%ED%E8%F9%E5
2)http://poiskslov.com/word/днище/
3)http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5&stype=0

Comment: Дно - поверхность, днище - часть конструкции.

Comment: 2Соан    
Спасибо. Но нигде нет примеров употреьления. 
Что ж тогда Гвидон у бочки "вышиб дно - и вышел вон"?
И еще вопрос. _**Сколько у бочки "днищ"?**_ 

>Дно - поверхность, днище - часть конструкции.  

Нет. Донья - это множественно к дно, в значении именно "элемент конструкции". У поверхности множественного нет. И про Гвидона - тож.

Answer (score 4):

Дно - общее название, бывает у водных объектов (морей, рек, озер), приспособлений, устройств, посуды, емкостей (бочек, кастрюль) и т.д.; днище - только у судов (хотя иногда переносят на другие объекты). "Дно корабля" - неправильно. Если, конечно, не имеется в виду "дно" трюма, т.е. емкости. Хотя и в этом случае моряки предпочитают говорить "палуба".

Answer (score 1):

Дно (мн. число донья) бывает в сосуда (в широком смысле), если эта поверхность рассматривается изнутри. Если же у сосуда есть внешняя нижняя поверхность, то это днище (мн. число днища). Примеры:

1. Бочка. Можно опустить что-то на ее дно, но нельзя на днище. Ее днище мы рассматриваем снаружи, если перевернем.
2. Корабль. Его дно - это самая нижняя палуба, на него можно спуститься. Его днище мы чиним, когда в корабле пробоина.
3. Бассейн, море, озеро, река, океан... У них есть дно, но нет днища.
4. Для небольших сосудов (стакан, рюмка, графин...) днище не употребляется, обе поверхности называются дном, откуда ни смотри. Но их днище обычно и не интересно, а если уж очень нужно, говорят "Вытри донышко у стакана, оно в сиропе".
5. Фигурально, для обозначения средоточия маргиналов, бедняков, преступников, употребимо только дно (вспомним "На дне").

   ```
                                                      Starper. 31 Авг'14
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Дно определяет уровень и качество поверхности внутри сосуда, котлована, реки. Там, где уровень не постоянен, употребляют определительное "самое".

Говоря о днище, характеризуют форму и материал основания предмета.